# Getting "Note: duplicate definition of library class" Proguard

Tags: java, android, spring, obfuscation, android-proguard

Below is the `application.pro` which is the configuration to obfuscate the spring related standalone application:

```
# This ProGuard configuration file illustrates how to process applications.
# Usage:
#     java -jar proguard.jar @applications.pro
#

# Specify the input jars, output jars, and library jars.

-injars  xyz.jar
-outjars xyz_out.jar

-libraryjars C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_20\jre\lib\rt.jar
-libraryjars <LocationOfJar>/xyz.jar
#-libraryjars servlet.jar
#-libraryjars jai_core.jar
#...

# Save the obfuscation mapping to a file, so you can de-obfuscate any stack
# traces later on. Keep a fixed source file attribute and all line number
# tables to get line numbers in the stack traces.
# You can comment this out if you're not interested in stack traces.

-printmapping out.map
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable

# Preserve all annotations.

-keepattributes *Annotation*

# You can print out the seeds that are matching the keep options below.

#-printseeds out.seeds

# Preserve all public applications.

-keepclasseswithmembers public class * {
    public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
}

# Preserve all native method names and the names of their classes.

-keepclasseswithmembernames,includedescriptorclasses class * {
    native <methods>;
}

# Preserve the special static methods that are required in all enumeration
# classes.

-keepclassmembers,allowoptimization enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

# Explicitly preserve all serialization members. The Serializable interface
# is only a marker interface, so it wouldn't save them.
# You can comment this out if your application doesn't use serialization.
# If your code contains serializable classes that have to be backward 
# compatible, please refer to the manual.

-keepclassmembers class * implements java.io.Serializable {
    static final long serialVersionUID;
    static final java.io.ObjectStreamField[] serialPersistentFields;
    private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream);
    private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream);
    java.lang.Object writeReplace();
    java.lang.Object readResolve();
}

# Your application may contain more items that need to be preserved; 
# typically classes that are dynamically created using Class.forName:

# -keep public class mypackage.MyClass
# -keep public interface mypackage.MyInterface
# -keep public class * implements mypackage.MyInterface


#Warnings to be removed. Otherwise maven plugin stops, but not dangerous
-keep public class com.sun.xml.internal.**
-keep public class com.sun.istack.internal.**
-keep public class org.codehaus.jackson.**
-keep public class org.springframework.**
-keep public class java.awt.**
-keep public class javax.security.**
-keep public class java.beans.**
-keep public class javax.xml.**
-keep public class java.util.**
-keep public class org.w3c.dom.**
-keep public class com.google.common.**
-keep public class org.apache.**
-keep public class org.xnio.**
-keep public class javax.xml.**
-keep public class java.time.**
-keep public class com.sun.corba.**
-keep public class org.hibernate.**
-keep public class antlr.**

-dontwarn com.sun.xml.internal.**
-dontwarn com.sun.istack.internal.**
-dontwarn org.codehaus.jackson.**
-dontwarn org.springframework.**
-dontwarn java.awt.**
-dontwarn javax.security.**
-dontwarn java.beans.**
-dontwarn javax.xml.**
-dontwarn java.util.**
-dontwarn org.w3c.dom.**
-dontwarn com.google.common.**
-dontwarn org.apache.**
-dontwarn org.xnio.**
-dontwarn javax.xml.**
-dontwarn java.time.**
-dontwarn com.sun.corba.**
-dontwarn org.hibernate.**
-dontwarn antlr.**
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
```

When I run:

> java -jar proguard.jar @applications.pro

I get this below error:

> Note: duplicate definition of library class

And output is not generated as given in the `application.pro`:

```
Note: there were 166 classes trying to access generic signatures using reflection.
      You should consider keeping the signature attributes
      (using '-keepattributes Signature').
      (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#attributes)
Note: there were 21 classes trying to access enclosing classes using reflection.
      You should consider keeping the inner classes attributes
      (using '-keepattributes InnerClasses').
      (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#attributes)
Note: there were 5 classes trying to access enclosing methods using reflection.
      You should consider keeping the enclosing method attributes
      (using '-keepattributes InnerClasses,EnclosingMethod').
      (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#attributes)
Note: there were 563 library classes explicitly being kept.
      You don't need to keep library classes; they are already left unchanged.
      (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#libraryclass)
Note: there were 55 unresolved dynamic references to classes or interfaces.
      You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
      (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#dynamicalclass)
Note: there were 4 class casts of dynamically created class instances.
      You might consider explicitly keeping the mentioned classes and/or
      their implementations (using '-keep').
      (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#dynamicalclasscast)
Note: there were 292 accesses to class members by means of introspection.
      You should consider explicitly keeping the mentioned class members
      (using '-keep' or '-keepclassmembers').
      (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#dynamicalclassmember)
Warning: there were 5329 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
         You may need to add missing library jars or update their versions.
         If your code works fine without the missing classes, you can suppress
         the warnings with '-dontwarn' options.
         (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedclass)
Warning: there were 117 instances of library classes depending on program classes.
         You must avoid such dependencies, since the program classes will
         be processed, while the library classes will remain unchanged.
         (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#dependency)
Warning: there were 42 unresolved references to program class members.
         Your input classes appear to be inconsistent.
         You may need to recompile the code.
         (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedprogramclassmember)
Error: Please correct the above warnings first.
```

How to resolve this issue?